# Concat audio files then call create file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, async-await

I am new and am trying to concat a folder of audio files and then stream the create file with ffmpeg in node.js.

I thought I could call the function that creates the file with await and then when it's done the code would continue allowing me to call the created file. However thats not whats happening. I am getting a "file undefined"

Main function

```
//CONCATS THE FILES
  await concatAudio(supportedFileTypes.supportedAudioTypes, `${path}${config[typeKey].audio_directory}`);

  // CALLS THE FILE CREATED FROM concatAudio
  const randomSong = await getRandomFileWithExtensionFromPath(
    supportedFileTypes.supportedAudioTypes,
    `${path}${config[typeKey].audio_final}`
  );
```

concatAudio function

```
var audioconcat = require('audioconcat');
const getRandomFileWithExtensionFromPath = require('./randomFile');
const find = require('find');

// Async Function to get a random file from a path
module.exports = async (extensions, path) => {
  // Find al of our files with the extensions
  let allFiles = [];

  extensions.forEach(extension => {
    allFiles = [...allFiles, ...find.fileSync(extension, path)];
  });

  await audioconcat(allFiles)
    .concat('./live-stream-radio/final/all.mp3')
    .on('start', function(command) {
      console.log('ffmpeg process started:', command);
    })
    .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.error('Error:', err);
      console.error('ffmpeg stderr:', stderr);
    })
    .on('end', function(output) {
      console.error('Audio created in:', output);
    });

  // Return a random file

  // return '/Users/Semmes/Downloads/live-stream-radio-ffmpeg-builds/live-stream-radio/final/all.mp3';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it wrapping into a Promise, I adapted my solution to your script (I don't tested in this code, but is almost the same), I hope this helps someone:

```
var audioconcat = require('audioconcat');
const getRandomFileWithExtensionFromPath = require('./randomFile');
const find = require('find');

// Async Function to get a random file from a path
module.exports = async (extensions, path) => {
  // Find al of our files with the extensions
  let allFiles = [];

  extensions.forEach(extension => {
    allFiles = [...allFiles, ...find.fileSync(extension, path)];
  });

  const concatPromise = new Promise(async (resolve, error) => {
    audioconcat(allFiles)
        .concat('./live-stream-radio/final/all.mp3')
        .on('start', function(command) {
            console.log('ffmpeg process started:', command);
        })
        .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            console.error('Error:', err);
            console.error('ffmpeg stderr:', stderr);
            error(err);
        })
        .on('end', function(output) {
            console.error('Audio created in:', output);
            resolve(otuput);
        });
    });

// Return a random file (this should return the output string)
return await concatPromise();

  // return '/Users/Semmes/Downloads/live-stream-radio-ffmpeg-builds/live-stream-radio/final/all.mp3';
};
```